# Different ways to access data from Azure Data Share to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-share

We are working on implementing a new project in Azure. The idea is to move out of on-premise systems into the cloud as we have our vendors, partners and clients moving into the cloud. The option we are trying out is to use Azure Data Share and have Azure SQL Database subscribe to the data.

The thing we are now trying to explore is once a new data snapshot is created how do we import this data into Azure SQL Database?

For instance we have Partner information and this information is made available via Azure Data Share and new data snapshot is created daily.

The part that I am not sure of is how to synchronize this data between Azure Data Share and Azure SQL Database.

Also, Is there an api available to expose this data out to external vendors, partners or clients from Azure SQL Database after we have data sync to Azure SQL Database from Azure Data Share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure Data Share -> Azure SQL Database

Yes, Azure SQL Database is a supported.

> Azure Data Share -> SQL Server Database (on-prem)? Is this option supported?

No, SQL Server Database (on-prem) is not supported.

> Is there an api that could be consumed to read data?

Unfortunately, there is no such API that could be consumed to read data.

Azure Data Share enables organizations to simply and securely share data with multiple customers and partners. In just a few clicks, you can provision a new data share account, add datasets, and invite your customers and partners to your data share. Data providers are always in control of the data that they have shared. Azure Data Share makes it simple to manage and monitor what data was shared, when and by whom.

Azure Data Share helps enhance insights by making it easy to combine data from third parties to enrich analytics and AI scenarios. Easily use the power of Azure analytics tools to prepare, process, and analyze data shared using Azure Data Share.

> Which Azure data stores does Data Share support?

Data Share supports data sharing to and from Azure Synapse Analytics, Azure SQL Database, Azure Data Lake Storage, Azure Blob Storage, and Azure Data Explorer. Data Share will support more Azure data stores in the future.

The below table details the supported data sources for Azure Data Share.

[image]

> How to synchronize this data between Azure Data Share and Azure SQL Database.

You need to choose “Snapshot setting” to refresh data automatically.

A data provider can configure a data share with a snapshot setting. This allows incremental updates to be received on a regular schedule, either daily or hourly. Once configured, the data consumer has the option to enable the schedule.

[image]